# After update trigger fires twice, first with no updated info, second with info

Tags: apex, trigger, event, update, after

I'm writing a trigger that chops up a long-text field on an event activity record and puts it into the appropriate fields on the related contact's record. The problem is, the code seems to be firing twice.

- **1st fire:** when I `System.debug()` the code, it showed that the first time, the updated text from the event field did not show.
- **2nd fire:** when I `System.debug()` the code it shows the information from the event field.

**CODE BELOW:**

```
 trigger remeetUpdate on Event (after update) {
    Event e = Trigger.new[0];

    List<Contact> c = [
        SELECT Id, Person_s_met_Place_met__c, Current_Responsibilities__c, Personality_Impression__c, Additional_Information__c, Hot_Buttons__c, Companies_Introducing_to__c, Companies_Met_in_the_past__c
        FROM Contact
        Where Contact.Id = :e.WhoId
    ];

    if (e.Write_up_completed__c == True && e.Type__c == 'Remeet') {
        // chop up the comments field
        // stick them in the write-up field

        String comments = e.Comments__c;
        List<String> sections = new List<String>();

        List<String> contactFields = new List<String>();
        contactFields.add('Person_s_met_Place_met__c');
        contactFields.add('Personality_Impression__c');
        contactFields.add('Current_Responsibilities__c');
        contactFields.add('Additional_Information__c');
        contactFields.add('Companies_met_in_the_past__c');
        contactFields.add('Companies_Introducing_to__c');
        contactFields.add('Hot_Buttons__c');

        List<String> commentArray = new List<String>();

        sections = comments.split('IMPRESSION:|CURRENT POSITION/ RESPONSIBILITIES:|ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:|COMPANIES MET RECENTLY:|COMPANIES INTRODUCING TO:|UPDATED HOT BUTTONS:');
        for (Integer i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                sections[0] = sections[0].replace('CONSULTANTS MET, DATE, AND PLACE:', 'REMEET ' + e.StartDateTime);
                sections[0] = sections[0] + '*****' + '\n';
                commentArray.add(sections[0]);
            } else {
                commentArray.add('REMEET ' + e.StartDateTime + sections[i] + '*****' + '\n');
            }  
        }

        for (Integer j = 0; j < commentArray.size(); j++) {
            c[0].put(contactFields[j], commentArray[j] + c[0].get(contactFields[j]));
        }

        update c[0];
    }
}
```

Feels like a bit of a catch 22. I can't use a helper class to tell it to only fire once because the first time the information isn't getting through to the contact record.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. This issue was a combination of pointing to the wrong field and multiple after update triggers firing. I pointed to the correct "Description" field on the event rather than a custom formula field that copies the description field. I also put in a helper class to only allow the trigger to update once.